# How to debug a project half by python half by bash, both will interact in vscode

Tags: python, bash, visual-studio-code, debugging, vscode-debugger

I have a project that runs on centos. It's mostly python and bash in it. right now I can debug them separately in vscode. but I want to debug them together. For example a start.sh has

```
python3 . /build.py "$@"
```

and I can't jump to build.py.

it's launch.json in my vscode

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",            
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
        },
        {
            "type":"bashdb",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Bash : Debug",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/debugging#_compound-launch-configurations

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

[minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: May I know what's going on with the problem? If it has been solved, can you change the status of the answer to help more people with similar problems.

Comment: sorry，I still don't know how to fix it.